# How to add additional skip connection path to U-net?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

Hi I'm working on a CT scan image segmentation task. I've extracted jpeg image from DICOM from two different CT window (WW and WL). But the masks are the same.

Now, I want to add an additional path to U-net with a second set of the input images (see image). I think it might give additional context to the network. But, I'm not sure how to implement this.

[image: Red parts to be added]

This is my U-net model.

```
import tensorflow as tf


IMG_WIDTH = 128
IMG_HEIGHT = 128
IMG_CHANNELS = 3


#Build the model
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
s = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(inputs)

#Contraction path
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(s)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c1)
p1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)

c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p1)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c2)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c2)
p2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2)
 
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p2)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c3)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c3)
p3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3)
 
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p3)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c4)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c4)
p4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(c4)
 
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p4)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(c5)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c5)

#Expansive path 
u6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
u6 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u6, c4])
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c6)
 
u7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
u7 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u7, c3])
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c7)
 
u8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
u8 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u8, c2])
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c8)
 
u9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
u9 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c9)
 
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(c9)
 
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a labda layer to split the channels like this

```
x0 = Lambda(lambda x : x[:,:,:,0])(x)
x1 = Lambda(lambda x : x[:,:,:,1])(x)
```

in this way you get the channel with the new input and then you concatenate it at the last layer like this

```
u9 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u9, c1, x1], axis=3)
```

so you elaborate on `x0` and on the last block you concatenate again with `x1`